# Get data from DBUS org.freedesktop.dbus and java - org.freedesktop.DBus$Error$UnknownMethod: Method doesn't exist

Tags: java, interface, dbus

I try to get some data from a dbus service and work with it in Java.

I can get the information in cli with the following command:

```
dbus-send --print-reply --system --dest=com.victronenergy.solarcharger.ttyUSB0 /Dc/0/Voltage com.victronenergy.BusItem.GetValue
```

The result is:

```
method return time=1538903662.321580 sender=:1.14 -> destination=:1.806 serial=335692 reply_serial=2
variant       double 13.43
```

What I tried to get this data in Java, is:

After hours of reading, I created an Interface.

```
package javadbus;

import java.util.Map;
import org.freedesktop.dbus.DBusInterface;
import org.freedesktop.dbus.DBusSignal;
import org.freedesktop.dbus.Variant;
import org.freedesktop.dbus.exceptions.DBusException;
public interface BusItem extends DBusInterface
{
   public static class PropertiesChanged extends DBusSignal
   {
      public final Map<String,Variant> changes;
      public PropertiesChanged(String path, Map<String,Variant> changes) throws DBusException
      {
         super(path, changes);
         this.changes = changes;
      }
   }

  public String GetDescription(String language, int length);
  public Variant GetValue();
  public String GetText();
  public int SetValue(Variant value);
  public Variant GetMin();
  public Variant GetMax();
  public int SetDefault();
  public Variant GetDefault();

}
```

Here I call getConnection() and getRemoteObject() successfully.

```
package javadbus;
import org.freedesktop.dbus.DBusConnection;
import org.freedesktop.dbus.exceptions.DBusException;
import org.freedesktop.dbus.Variant;

public class VictronEnergyDBusSolarCharger {

private String port;
private DBusConnection conn;

public VictronEnergyDBusSolarCharger(String port) {
    this.port = port;
    try {
        this.conn = DBusConnection.getConnection(DBusConnection.SYSTEM);
    } catch (DBusException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private String getData(String item) {
    BusItem bi;
    String data = null;
    Variant vData = null;
    try {
        bi = (BusItem)conn.getRemoteObject("com.victronenergy.solarcharger." + this.port, item, BusItem.class);
        vData = bi.GetValue();
        //data = bi.GetText();
    } catch (DBusException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return data;
}
...
}
```

It was a big task to resolve all dependecies and get the code compiled. But finaly I did it. So, javac now runs without errors.

But if I try to call the Method GetValue(), I get the following Exception:

```
[Sender] INFO org.freedesktop.dbus.MessageWriter - <= MethodCall(0,1) { Path=>/org/freedesktop/DBus, Interface=>org.freedesktop.DBus, Member=>Hello, Destination=>org.freedesktop.DBus } { }
[Sender] INFO org.freedesktop.dbus.MessageWriter - <= MethodCall(0,3) { Path=>/Dc/0/Voltage, Interface=>javadbus.BusItem, Member=>GetValue, Destination=>com.victronenergy.solarcharger.ttyUSB0 } { }
Exception in thread "main" org.freedesktop.DBus$Error$UnknownMethod: Method "GetValue" with signature "" on interface "javadbus.BusItem" doesn't exist
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.freedesktop.dbus.Error.getException(Error.java:141)
        at org.freedesktop.dbus.Error.throwException(Error.java:171)
        at org.freedesktop.dbus.RemoteInvocationHandler.executeRemoteMethod(RemoteInvocationHandler.java:158)
        at org.freedesktop.dbus.RemoteInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteInvocationHandler.java:222)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1.GetValue(Unknown Source)
        at javadbus.VictronEnergyDBusSolarCharger.getData(VictronEnergyDBusSolarCharger.java:28)
        at javadbus.VictronEnergyDBusSolarCharger.getDcV(VictronEnergyDBusSolarCharger.java:38)
        at javadbus.MainClass.main(MainClass.java:7)
```

Is it necessary to make a implementation of this Method GetValue? But why e.g. how should I do this? I only want to get this Information and not provide it like a Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why was it a big task to get all dependencies?
dbus-java library and dependencies are all available at maven central, so a proper maven project should just work out-of-the-box.

Back to topic:

You don't have to implement `GetValue()`, but you need a suitable java interface for `BusItem`.

As far as I can see in the documentation of victronenergy (https://www.victronenergy.com/live/open_source:ccgx:d-bus) , your interface is not correct.

You provide `SetDefault()`/`GetDefault()` methods, which are only available on `com.victronenergy.settings` Objects, but you want to retrieve a `com.victronenergy.BusItem` (no part of the `com.victronenergy.settings` package).

This is one error. The second error is: you use the wrong package name for your `BusItem` class.

In your case DBus will try to resolve an object with the path `javadbus.BusItem` which is not provided by the connected BusAddress `com.victronenergy.solarcharger.ttyUSB0`.

The `BusItem` class has to be in package `com.victronenergy` or you have to use the annotation `@DBusInterfaceName("com.victronenergy.BusItem")`.

The annotation will tell the DBus library to ignore the java package/class name and use the one provided in the annotation.

Answer (score 0):

The Inteface BusItem had been created by CreateInterface-Script from https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-java/dbus-java/dbus-javase10.html and the XML from Introspect()

But you solved my real problem. I used the annotation @DBusInterfaceName("com.victronenergy.BusItem") now. No Exception anymore an i get data from my solarcharger. Thank you so much!